# How do I get data to show up in my graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to get my data to show up in my graph, however I get an error that says that my data is "NaN" after I converted the Year and Miles column from strings to integers.

I'm guessing that it's something with my x_scale & y_scale...?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <description>
        <!--charts - avg vehicle trip per mile, source: http://nhts.ornl.gov/2009/pub/stt.pdf-->
    </description>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // global variables
        var dataset;

        d3.csv("avgVehicleTripLengthMiles.csv", function (error, data) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log(data);
            }

            // once loaded, data is copied to dataset because js is asynchronous
            dataset = data;

            createScatterplot();

        });

        /*
                function typeConv() {
                    // type conversion from string to integer
                    var typeConv = dataset.forEach(function (d) {
                        d["Year"] = +d["Year"];
                        d["Miles"] = +d["Miles"];
                        return d;
                    });
                }
        */
        function createScatterplot() {

            // TEST
            var typeConv = dataset.forEach(function (d) {
                d["Year"] = +d["Year"];
                d["Miles"] = +d["Miles"];
                return d;
            });

            var title = d3.select("body")
                .append("h4")
                .text("Avg. Vehicle Trip Length per Mile");

            // dimensions of canvas
            var padding = 30;

            var margin = {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 40,
                    bottom: 20,
                    left: 40
                },
                w = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
                h = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            // create svg canvas
            var svg_canvas = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom);

            // create scale for axis
            var x_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([1969, 2009]).range([padding, w - padding * 2]);

            var y_scale =
                d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 20]).range([h - padding, padding]);

            // r_scale created specifically for circles' radius to be mapped unto axes
            var r_scale =
                d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function (d) {
                    return d[1];
                })]).range([0, 20]);

            // define axis & ticks // .ticks(5) to x_axis and .ticks(1) to y_axis
            var x_axis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x_scale);

            var y_axis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y_scale);

            // create group, "g" element, to create x_axis and y_axis
            var x_group = svg_canvas.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
                .call(x_axis);

            var y_group = svg_canvas.append("g")
                .attr("class", "axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
                .call(y_axis);

            // create circles
            svg_canvas.selectAll("circle")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function (d) {
                    return x_scale(d[0]);
                })
                .attr("cy", function (d) {
                    console.log(d); // TEST
                    return y_scale(d[1]);
                })
                .attr("cr", function (d) {
                    return r_scale(d[1]);
                });
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I recommend using `console.log()` at each step, particularly before and after your type conversion function. Btw, years are (usually) categories, and thus should not be converted from strings.

Comment: It's not clear where you're specifying which key in a tuple applies to which scale. In looking at [the documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#joining-data), do you need to clarify this in your `data()` call? e.g., `.data(data, function(d) { ... })`. In addition, the `.append("circle")` call and subsequent `.attr()` calls appear to be copied from [this doc page](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/), which doesn't seem relevant to what I understand you're trying to do.

Comment: Attempting to run the code (with fake data), the full error appears to be `Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cy="NaN"`, which appears several times in my console. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// global variables
    var dataset;

    d3.csv("avgVehicleTripLengthMiles.csv", function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }

        // once loaded, data is copied to dataset because js is asynchronous
        dataset = data;

        createScatterplot();

    });

    function createScatterplot() {

        // TEST
        var typeConv = dataset.forEach(function (d) {
            // d["Year"] = +d["Year"];
            d["Miles"] = +d["Miles"];
            // return d;
        });

        var title = d3.select("body")
            .append("h4")
            .text("Avg. Vehicle Trip Length per Mile");

        // dimensions of canvas
        var padding = 30;

        var margin = {
                top: 20,
                right: 40,
                bottom: 20,
                left: 40
            },
            w = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
            h = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        // create svg canvas
        var svg_canvas = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom);

        // create scale for axis
        var x_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([1965, 2009]).range([padding, w - padding * 2]);

        var y_scale =
            d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 20]).range([h - padding, padding]);

        // r_scale created specifically for circles' radius to be mapped unto axes
        var r_scale =
            d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function (d) {
                return d[1];
            })]).range([0, 20]);

        // define axis & ticks // .ticks(5) to x_axis and .ticks(1) to y_axis
        var x_axis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x_scale);

        var y_axis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y_scale);

        // create group, "g" element, to create x_axis and y_axis
        var x_group = svg_canvas.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
            .call(x_axis);

        var y_group = svg_canvas.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
            .call(y_axis);

        // create & color circles
        svg_canvas.selectAll("circle")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function (d) {
                return x_scale(d["Year"]);
            })
            .attr("cy", function (d) {
                return y_scale(d["Miles"]);
            })
            .attr("r", function (d) {
                return 5;
            })
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                if (d["Trip Purpose"] === "All Purposes") {
                    return "pink";
                } else if (d["Trip Purpose"] === "To or From Work") {
                    return "red";
                } else if (d["Trip Purpose"] === "Shopping") {
                    return "blue";
                } else if (d["Trip Purpose"] === "Other Family/Personal Errands") {
                    return "green";
                } else if (d["Trip Purpose"] === "Social and Recreational") {
                    return "gray";
                };
            });

        // create text label for x-axis
        svg_canvas.append("text")
            .attr("x", w / 2)
            .attr("y", h + margin.top + 20)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("Year");

        // create text label for y-axis
        svg_canvas.append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("x", (0 - margin.left / 2))
            .attr("y", (h/2))
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("Miles");
```

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT (new answer):

There are  several issues, and I'll try to step through them one by one.

In order to test, I had to make up my own data. My test CSV file looked like this (so your final answer might change slightly if your file is different)

```
Year,Miles
2006,5.0
2007,7.2
2008,19.3
```

1. As was pointed out by @altocumulus in the comments above, your `.attr()` calls are referencing non-existant indexes, which might be part of the trouble.
2. The radius attribute for circles is `r`, not `cr`
3. I simplified the code by not calling a function for `r`, but rather doing a static value. You may want to play further with this.

The significantly changed portion of code is

```
svg_canvas.selectAll("circle")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function (d) {
                return x_scale(d["Year"]);
            })
            .attr("cy", function (d) {
                return y_scale(d["Miles"]);
            })
            .attr("r", function (d) {
                return 5;
                //return r_scale(d[1]);
            });
```

You still have an issue with the x-axis acting like numbers, and not dates, making `2006` look like `2,006`, for example. I haven't solved that issue here.

Lastly, I feel like you're complicating your code for no reason by trying to handle margin AND padding via the D3 code, when these end up meaning similar things in the Javascript context. I suggest accomplishing most of the margin/padding via CSS, which would simplify your code. Another example of an unnecessary complication is in the previous answer, below.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/n3hfnLyf/)

#### OLD (incomplete, incorrect) ANSWER:

The return value of [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is `undefined`, so it can't be assigned.

```
        dataset.forEach(function (d) {
            //d["Year"] = +d["Year"];
            d["Miles"] = +d["Miles"];
            // NOT NEEDED: return d;
        });
```

If you need to keep your converted array separate, use `Array.map()`.

Comment: The assignment of `undefined` to the variable `typeConv` is perfectly legal. And, since `typeConv` is never used, this won't be a problem at all.

Comment: You're right. "Can't be assigned" is not wholly correct, as `undefined` may be assigned. "Not usefully assigned" would have been better. And if `typeConv` is never used (you're correct that it's not, in the provided code), then it shouldn't be defined.

Comment: I agree, that it *shouldn't* be defined, and we would be seeing a whole lot less questions on this site, if people kept their code clean ;-) But, because it doesn't cause any errors either, this is not the root of the problem, and, unfortunately, your answer won't solve it.

Comment: @altocumulus: Your comment caused me to revisit. After seeing the first error, I short-circuited. I've since edited the above answer to be more complete, and solve the question. (Down the rabbit hole I go! Whee!) If you think the new answer works, I'd appreciate you reverting the down vote.

Comment: Now, that looks much more of an answer! Personally, I'd prefer throwing out the old answer section as well as the "EDIT..." heading. As the edits are still available via the revision history, there is no need for any self-flagellation here. Now let's wait if @Laura is able to shed some more light on this...

Comment: I left it to give context to the comments and suggest to a new visitor the answer had changed since the downvote. Feel free to edit as you like.